# How to implement Authorization (Guard) in Laravel , while not using make:auth command

Tags: laravel

I am trying to implement a `gate` system for an app, which checks if a user is 'superadmin', 'admin' or 'user'. The thing is I am **not** using, and don't want to use the `php artisan make:auth` command. However, I am using the `Auth` facade to check the user credentioals.

Although the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization) mentions the usage of *guards*, but I am not sure if they can be implemented with the `make:auth` command.

Can someone give some examples or ideas on how to use **Guards** in Laravel?

Comment: You don't use guards for authorization, they are used for authentication, for authorization you should use [gates](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#gates) and [policies](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#creating-policies).

Comment: @Remul Yes. I corrected it.

Comment: @daffaquraisy Yes. But their documentation mentions the usage of gate and policies using `make:auth` command. I didn't use it in my project so I dont know how to impement `gates`

Comment: There is not a single mention of `make:auth` in the authorization documentation. As long as you use Laravels authentication system (with or without make:auth / jetstream / fortify / breeze) you can easily use gates and policies.

Comment: No, you don't have to run ```make:auth```

Comment: @daffaquraisy How do I define the roles of each user?

Comment: @Skumar check my new answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll explain it from the start.

First you have to define the gates, gates are defined within the boot method of the App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider.php file :

```
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        // 'manage-posts' is name of the gate
        Gate::define('manage-posts', function ($user) {
            // and the role is my column on table users
            return $user->role == 'ADMIN';
        });
    }
```

So to access the manage-posts gate the user should have the role admin in their account.

To authorize an action using gates, you should use the allows or denies methods provided by the Gate facade.

in your PostController, you can write constructor like this (if you don't want to declare it repeatly) :

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {

            if (Gate::allows('manage-posts')) return $next($request);
            abort(403, 'You are not an admin');
        });
    }
}
```

or if you want declare it on specific method, you can write like this :

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        if (Gate::allows('manage-posts')) {
            $post = \App\Post::findOrFail($id);
            $post->delete();

            return redirect()->route('posts.index', [$id])->with('status', 'Post successfully deleted.');
        }
        abort(403, 'You are not an admin');
    }
}
```

and boom, the gate is ready to do their job, if there is a user trying to hit the route that protected by gates, laravel will automaticly return error 403.

Last if you need show menus based on role, you can use blade directive @can and define the gate name, example :

```
<ul>
 @can('manage-posts', $user ?? '')
  <li>Coffee</li>
 @endcan
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

If the user have the requirement, the user can see the coffe menu, and if not, just 2 menus available.

I think that's enough for implementation using gate, you can visit laravel docs for more references https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#gates, and sorry for my bad english, just trying to help, thank you for reading this.

Comment: btw, what would be my code, if the registration table (the table which is filled up when a user signs up) is not `users` ,but say `tbl_cust_reg` ?

Comment: There's no problem with that, you can name you're table whatever you want

Comment: I did, and it's working. Except at one location - check this out

Comment: `<nav class="navbar navbar-expand sticky-top navbar-dark @if(auth()->check())  @can('manage-users')bg-danger text-white @endcan @can('manage-contact-msg' )style='background-color:yellow;color:white' @endcan bg-dark @else bg-info @endif">`

Comment: This does not change colour to red, if the user is admin.

Comment: even though I used `@can('manage-users', $user ? ' ' )`

Comment: And I would also like to know  if the registration table (the table which is filled up when a user signs up) is not users ,but say tbl_cust_reg ?, because one of our projects use the latter

Comment: Just use if statement for that, you don't have to use ```@can```, ```@if(/Auth::user()->role == 'admin') bg-red @endif```, ```@can``` directive just for authorization

Comment: I thought of that, but why not use something available ? I thought I made a syntax error. I will work around  But, if you can please also explain what code to write if my table is `tbl_cust_reg`

Comment: The only configuration if your table is not users, you can just write this in your model ```protected $table = 'tbl_cust_reg';```

Comment: Alright. I will try that. We never used `Model`, so I don't know how that works